# css кастомизация вывода произвольных полей

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Сделал произвольное поле в wordpress в которое должен вводиться бренд производителя. [image: скриншот архива продукта]

Каким способом я могу подключиться к этому тексту в css? Может есть способ задать ему класс через functions? В инспекторе всё выглядит так[image: скрин 2]

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<span class="brand">'.get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_text_field', true ) . '</span>';
```

Не знал, что можно так делать - теперь знаю.